# Are CTE's not allowed in SQLLab?

Tags: sql-server, common-table-expression, apache-superset

When running the below in `/superset/sqllab/`

```
";WITH cteData AS (
SELECT TOP (100) * FROM [dbo].[Response]
) x
SELECT * 
FROM cteData"
```

I get the following error:

> mssql error:(156, b"Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WITH'.DB-Lib error message 20018, severity 15:\nGeneral SQL Server error: Check messages from the SQL Server\nDB-Lib error message 20018, severity 15:\nGeneral SQL Server error: Check messages from the SQL Server\nDB-Lib error message 20018, severity 15:\nGeneral SQL Server error: Check messages from the SQL Server\nDB-Lib error message 20018, severity 15:\nGeneral SQL Server error: Check messages from the SQL Server\n")

It's clearly unhappy about the WITH part of my CTE, however removing just throws an incorrect syntax error. I have been trying to find other ways to write my queries, to no avail.

Comment: If I were to save the query as a proc on the server side, It runs fine, but I get the same error no the visualization side.

Comment: A CTE is just another form of sub-query, so use a sub-query instead.

Comment: Have you tried removing ";" in the front of your "WITH"?

Answer (score 1):

This was fixed in Feb 2022 and implemented in Superset versions 1.5.0 and up.  CTEs are now supported in SQL Lab with a MSSQL back end.  Here's the pull request that did it: https://github.com/apache/superset/pull/18567